# Double Postback occurs when using FireFox not with Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, iis, networking

I hosted application on IIS and URL is https://example.com ,I don't understand when i use this URL with Firefox the double post-back occurs, but when i run the same URL with chrome nothing is happen all things working smoothly . the same URL i am using from last 7 years even on Firefox nothing problems occurs but recently we change our server, all certificate for SSL are right, but i don't understand why this happening.

i think may be the certificate making this problem. if yes then what are setting which i can do for stop this double post-back.
and may be the certificate is supporting the chrome.

Comment: A response should end with a 200 OK status.  You may be getting one chunk and see the first response returning with 100 Continue.  HTTP has two mode 1)HTTP 1.0 : Stream Mode where everything is returned in one response 2)HTTP 1.1 : Chunk Mode where response can be one or more chunks.  After each chunk you a Next Chunk message is sent (and if not you get a timeout).  The mode is determined when the client sends the first request which can contain either 1.0 or 1.1.

Comment: Then the server can do a few different things 1) Only Support one mode and ignore the other mode (or return an error if server doesn't support the mode) 2) Support either mode depending when client sends

Comment: @jdweng not getting

Comment: The double postback could be occurring because you are in chunk mode (1.1) where server is responding back in two chunks.

Comment: @jdweng i got it. thanks. but how can i change 1.1 to 2.0

Comment: I think you mean 1.0 :             HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("URI");
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: @jdweng can we done any setting on IIS. when i run my application i can see HTTP/1.1 protocol but when i publish same application on another server then same application with protocol HTTP/2. can you tell me from where i can change the setting without any code.

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis

Comment: @jdweng thanks for link, yes i already tried all the thing and also i have my own SSL certificate. I want to share one thing if i disable the setting in Firefox in about:config network.http.spdy.enabled.http2=false then the problem is solved.

can u help me to sort this condition, if this condition i can put into my code or server then it will help me alot. i can't set this condition to every user system can u suggest me how can i do.

Comment: what is your SSL setting in iis? did you set to accept? try to set the registry key 1. Navigate to the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters
2. Add 2 new REG_DWORD values, EnableHttp2Tls and EnableHttp2Cleartext, to this registry key. and set both values to 0.

Comment: Capture the Firefox request and see if there is a header that is sent to server which does the disable of HTTP/2.  Then add the same header to your c# request.  It may be the browser (user agent) option that is disabling the HTTP/2.